# Why am I getting the message "Cannot add child feature: primary keys are not available" in QField?

Tags: qgis, qfield, one-to-many, qfield-cloud

In QGIS, I have set up a one-to-many relation with a "plot" layer (parent) - a UUID field as the primary key - and a "stems" layer (child). I am attempting to set up another one-to-many relation with "stems" (parent) - a UUID as the primary key - and "stems_40" (child). I have used fk_plot as the referencing key in the stems layer, and I have used fk_stems as the referencing layer in stems_40.

The form field for fk_plot (in the stems layer properties) has "Editable' un-selected and has constraints "Not null" and "Enforce not null constraint" selected; the form field for fk_stems (in the stems_40 layer properties) is set-up exactly the same way as the "stems" layer.

Then in QField, when I create a new "stems" child from the layer "plot" everything works fine, but when I try to create a new "stems_40" child from the open "stems" layer form, I get the error message "Cannot add child feature: primary keys are not available."

I have tried saving changes to the "stems" and "plot" layers, then attempting to create the new "stems_40" child again, and I get the same message. What am I missing? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Does it work in QGIS but not in QField or does it fail on both ?

Comment: Yep. It works in QGIS just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured this out. For the parent primary key, I changed the UUID Widget Type to "Editable." This seemed to work. Since the UUID Generator Widget is read-only anyway, it still isn't actually editable by the user, so it can still stay unique. But I guess having the UUID Widget Type NOT "Editable" was even preventing the field from being filled-out automatically.

Comment: thanks, just ran in the same problem! 
please be so kind and mark your question as answered  :)